# Unit test cases for Callbacks using Junit

Tags: java, android, kotlin, junit4

I'm trying to write some unit-test cases for a class with functions that has callbacks as arguments (Please see code below)

```
class NetworkApi(private val url: String) {

    fun getToken(listener: (String) -> Unit) {
        Thread(Runnable {
            Thread.sleep(2000)
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(url)) listener("")
            else listener("Dummy token")
        }).start()
    }
}
```

and the unit test case is

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class NetworkApiTest {

    var networkApi: NetworkApi? = null

    @Test
    fun testEmptyToken() {
        networkApi = NetworkApi("")
        networkApi?.getToken {
            Assert.assertThat(it, isEmptyOrNullString())
        }
    }

}
```

And whenever I run this test case, I do get success all the time, no matter what values I send. I know that I'm not doing exact way.
Can someone please help me writing unit test cases for classes in JUnit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the test finishes before the callback is invoked and the `assert` is in the wrong thread.
You have to copy the result from the callback back to the main thread. Use a [`CompletableFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html). 
If you like to fail the test after a period of time you can use the `get` method with a timeout value:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class NetworkApiTest {
    var networkApi: NetworkApi? = null

    @Test
    fun testEmptyToken() {
        val future = CompletableFuture<String>()
        networkApi = NetworkApi("")
        networkApi?.getToken {
            future.complete(it)
        }
        val result = future.get(3,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        Assert.assertThat(it, isEmptyOrNullString())
    }
}
```